# Is there a way to refer to the index of a string as an int in order to manipulate and select certain characters in the string by their index number?

Tags: c#, string

I have two for loops here in order to compare each letter of a four character string to a secret code. Whenever the characters are equal, I want to output a B, however, only if the character is in the string but not in the same spot; similar to the game Mastermind. My solution was to put an extra condition in the if statement where if a!=b, the condition is satisfied. Is there a way for the integers a and b to represent the specific index number of the characters in the string?

```
for (int h = 0; h <= 3; h++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k <= 3; k++)
            {                    

                if (secretCode[h] == userGuess[k]&&a != b)
                {
                    Console.Write("B");
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: A string is also an array of char.  So you could say: `someString[0]` to get the char at the first index.

Comment: @maccettura There's no need to cast it to a char array, `char c = someString[0];` also works.

Comment: I'm unclear what exactly a and b are meant to be in this example...

Comment: @Gusman I realized that a moment after typing.  I think I had my comment edited a moment before you typed yours haha.  Thanks!

Comment: Why you need to compare char by char, why not compare the strings directly?

Comment: @maccettura: The OP already seems to be doing this in their code: `userGuess[k]`...

Comment: @Chris I guess this is what I get for reading just the title of a question.

Comment: Ehh, should it not simply be "h != k" instead of "a != b" - then you basically skip the check of the characters in the same position.

Comment: h and k are already the character positions

Comment: If you are trying to find the position of a character then `IndexOf` will do that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd(v=vs.110).aspx . I'm not 100% sure whether this is what you are trying to do or not so thought I'd link in case...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `IndexOf` to check the position in the string, something like this:

```
var a = "hello";
var b = "holle";

for(int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
{
    var idx = b.IndexOf(a[j]);

    //Check for -1, if it's -1 then the char isn't in the string
    if(idx != j && idx != -1) 
        Console.Write("B");
}
```